# Can't import csv with LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, load, load-data-infile

I need to download .csv file. I use this code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tablename.csv'
    INTO TABLE  testtable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

It returns nothing: 0 row(s) affected Records: 0 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0.

When I convert this .csv to .txt and use same code for txt - it works.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tablename.txt' 
    INTO TABLE  testtable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

What's problem with .csv can be? I tried to change ',' on ';' and '\n' on '\r\n'. It doesn't work.

There are first three rows with data from both files:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Did you just rename it? Or anything else?

Comment: I opened .csv-file in Excel and choose "save as..." .txt file. By this way I got .txt file :)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show an excerpt (first few lines) of both the .csv and the .txt file?

Comment: I loaded picture with first three rows from both files.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

> [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) – Linux Programmer's Manual – User Commands
>
> ...
>   If the lines of a file are terminated by CR, CRLF, or NEL, instead of
>   the Unix-standard LF, this will be reported.
>   ...

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.28    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> system file /path/to/file/tablename.csv
/path/to/file/tablename.csv: ASCII text

mysql> system cat /path/to/file/tablename.csv
number;name;quantity
255;Rick R;12
256;John S;13
257;Bryan W;14

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testtable`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtable` (
    ->   `number` INT UNSIGNED,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(20),
    ->   `quantity` INT UNSIGNED
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file/tablename.csv'
    ->     INTO TABLE `testtable`
    ->     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->     IGNORE 1 ROWS;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `number`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `quantity`
    -> FROM
    ->   `testtable`;
+--------+---------+----------+
| number | name    | quantity |
+--------+---------+----------+
|    255 | Rick R  |       12 |
|    256 | John S  |       13 |
|    257 | Bryan W |       14 |
+--------+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I copy your code (which is the same with my) and it still not work :( What nonobvious problem can be with table? Maybe I should try other line break characters? What else could it be?

Comment: @TeoRowersby: The problem seems to be the file encoding. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @TeoRowersby: Can you create a test file (.csv) in `Notepad` and see if you can load it correctly in MySQL?

Comment: I create .txt with 3 rows and then "save as..." .csv this file. Then I tryed to import csv by code above and it works :) You right, looks like problem was in file encoding. What type of encoding should I set? And the other problem is size of my main .csv file. Size is 5 Gb, so it can't be opened by excel. What can I do for change encoding im my main .csv file?

Comment: @TeoRowersby: The encoding depends on the encoding that you need. UTF8 is usually used but depend on the needs. It would be desirable to determine the actual encoding of the file to evaluate options.

Comment: I made an experiment: create nev .csv file for test. This file can't be imported as .csv. Then I chaned its encouding this file with Excel and "save as..." .csv in new encouding. And file .csv with new encouding have been imported! So how can I change encouding of my main .csv file of 5 Gb size, if it's too big to be opened with MS Excel?